# How to use git lfs with Visual Studio Team Services hosted build agents

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, git-lfs

I use git lfs to store the large files of my git repo. I then try to build this repo with hosted agents. My build is pretty simple. It has a single task: Execute PowerShell. In the invoked script, the first thing that I want to do is to fetch my lfs dependencies. I therefore have the following in my script:

```
& git lfs fetch
```

Unfortunately, my build fails with the following error:

```
2016-03-04T19:49:05.7021988Z ##[error]git: 'lfs' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
2016-03-04T19:49:05.7031986Z ##[error]Did you mean this?
2016-03-04T19:49:05.7041987Z ##[error]  flow
```

Since I can't install anything on hosted agents, how am I supposed to have git lfs available?

**EDIT**
In this issue, I am not talking about git lfs authentication problems as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34083386/check-out-git-lfs-files-on-vstf-build/35876342). I am strictly talking about the issue of calling `git lfs`.

Once you are able to call `git lfs`, look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35876342/2679757) to solve the authentication problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check out git-lfs files on VSTF build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34083386/check-out-git-lfs-files-on-vstf-build)

Comment: @DanielMann The possible duplicate talks about problems with oauth token. It does not talk abotu git lfs not being available from the command line.

Comment: Git LFS is now supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error message because git-lfs isn't installed on Hosted Build Agent by default.

And since you are using Hosted Build Agent, it would be a little troublesome to install git-lfs via Chocolatey on it as you don't have administrator permission. An alternative way would be download [the binary files for git-lfs](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/releases) directly and upload it into Source Control. Then you can invoke the git-tfs.exe with an absolute path in your script.

Answer (score 3):

Git LFS is now supported by default on the Hosted Build Controller. But you do need to enable it in your get sources step.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some more details around the solution provided by Eddie. `git lfs` is not a built-in command. It is a git [custom command](http://thediscoblog.com/blog/2014/03/29/custom-git-commands-in-3-steps/).

When you call `git lfs`, git.exe does not know about the `lfs` command. So it looks in the PATH environment variable and searches for a program named `git-lfs.exe`. Once found, it calls that program with the provided argument.

So calling `git-lfs.exe pull` is equivalent to calling `git.exe lfs pull`.

The solution suggested is therefore to download git-lfs.exe, add it your git repo (it should obviously not be tracked by LFS), and call git-lfs.exe.

It is also possible to add the folder that contains git-lfs.exe to your path environment variable. This makes it possible to use commands like `git.exe lfs pull` as you usually do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to install software and have internet access during build you might be able to install git-lfs using the [Chocolatey package](https://chocolatey.org/packages/git-lfs) in a cmd / PowerShell task prior to your git-lfs operation.